# MariaDB/Mysql SELECT from - to with Subquery

Tags: mysql, mariadb, subquery

I have a table 'Device' with an installed date and a customer:

| Id | DeviceName | Installed | Customer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 2021-10-10 | 1 |
| 2 | B | 2021-10-10 | 1 |
| 3 | A | 2021-10-20 | 2 |
| 4 | A | 2021-10-30 | 3 |

I need following results

| DeviceName | InstalledFrom | InstalledTo | Customer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2021-10-10 | 2021-10-20 | 1 |
| B | 2021-10-10 | NULL | 1 |
| A | 2021-10-20 | 2021-10-30 | 2 |
| A | 2021-10-30 | NULL | 3 |

Tried it with following SQL

```
select a.DeviceName, a.Installed as InstalledFrom, b.installed as InstalledTo, a.customer 
from Device a 
left outer join Device b on ( b.DeviceName = ( SELECT DeviceName 
                                               FROM Device 
                                               where DeviceName = a.DeviceName 
                                                 AND Installed > a.Installed 
                                               order by installed limit 1) )
```

but this does not give the desired result.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What is precise MySQL version? PS. `Installed` column format is not correct for DATE datatype.

Comment: Tried it on Server-Version: 10.1.37-MariaDB
and you are right, the DATE format is not correct, that was just an example. I changed it.

Comment: *Server-Version: 10.1.37-MariaDB* Ancient version... is it possible to upgrade to at least 10.2.2 which supports CTE and window functions LEAD/LAG?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test this:

```sql
SELECT t1.DeviceName,
       t1.Installed InstalledFrom,
       t2.Installed InstalledTo,
       t1.Customer
FROM Device t1
LEFT JOIN Device t2 ON t1.DeviceName = t2.DeviceName
                   AND t1.Installed < t2.Installed
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM Device t3
                   WHERE t1.DeviceName = t3.DeviceName
                   AND t1.Installed < t3.Installed
                   AND t3.Installed < t2.Installed )
```